# Converting str to int (or float) in sum()

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

With the following code

```
df = my_dict[key]
print(df)
inst_row = df.iloc[3]
print(inst_row)
inst_sum = inst_row.sum()
print(inst_sum)
```

The output based on the print commands are

```
df
                                     0           1              2  ...        1366           1367           1368
ID                                 185         278            451  ...      199622         199746         199940
A     484406.166667    493122.5  481308.166667  ...    481924.5  484088.333333  482801.166667
B     4,096       4,096          4,096  ...       4,096          4,096          4,096
C     87867392.0  87867392.0     87867392.0  ...  87867392.0     87867392.0     87867392.0

inst_row

[4 rows x 1369 columns]
0       87867392.0
1       87867392.0
2       87867392.0
3       87867392.0
4       87867392.0
           ...    
1364    87867392.0
1365    87867392.0
1366    87867392.0
1367    87867392.0
1368    87867392.0
Name: C, Length: 1369, dtype: object

isnt_sum

87867392.087867392.087867392.0......87867392.087867392.0
```

So it seems that the `sum()` concatenates all values as string. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your data to an int or float using `astype`:

```
df = my_dict[key]
print(df)
inst_row = df.iloc[3]
print(inst_row)
inst_sum = inst_row.astype(float).sum()
print(inst_sum)
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the type of `inst_row` to numbers? What you propose is that it converts each string to number for the sum(). This works but for further usage of `inst_row` I have to do the same thing several times.

Comment: You can save it back to the dataframe after converting. It will change the type.

Answer (score -1):

Use list comprehension:

```
inst_sum = [int(data) for data in inst_row].sum()
```